# Cleanest way to parse argument with Getopt::Long

Tags: perl

I use GetOpt to parse command-line arguments. I would like to add a new option "multi" which should get a string which looks as following: `key1=abc,key2=123,key3=xwz`.
I don't know how many custom keys user want to give but he can give minimax `5` keys. Also, I would like to put it in a hash with keys.
I'm looking for a good and clean way to implement it.

For starters, I thought of using `--multi {key1=abc,key2=123,key3=xwz}` but for some reason, it gets only
the first key `key1=abc`. Also I tried: `--multi {key1=abc},{key2=123},{key3=xwz}` but it feels kind of messy. I want to give the user the possibility to add arguments with `-` like `key1=./some_script.pl --help`. Part of the code:

```
my %arg;
GetOptions(
            "multi=s" => \$arg{"multi"},
}
```

Then I would like to somehow put those keys in the hash so it will be easy to use them. So I thought of using: `$arg{"multi"}{"key3"}` in order to get the value of `key3`.
How should I approach this feature? What is the cleanest way to do so?

To summarize it:

1. What is the best way to ask the user to give keys in order to get a similar situation to `key1=abc,key2=123,key3=xwz`, without using a file (giving options, not in a file way)? Meaning - how would you like, as a user of the script, to give those fields?
2. How to validate that user gave less than 5 keys?
3. How should I parse those keys and what is the best way to insert those keys into the hash map in the `multi` key.

Expected output: I would like to have a hash which looks like this: `$arg{"multi"}{"key3"}` and returns `xwz`.

Comment: Would `--multi key1=abc --multi key2=123 --multi key3=xwz` be acceptable? Also, `--multi {key1=abc,key2=...}` should also work and (depending on the vagaries of your shell) give you the complete value. If not, quote the value according to your shell: `--multi "{key1=abc,key2=...}"`. Learning how to quote values in your shell has nothing to do with Perl.

Comment: @ikegami yes, sorry. though it was clear.
@Corion we would like to implement with one flag because it does really look "pretty" with multi same flags. Also, I would like to implement without forcing user to use quotes `"`.

Comment: @TTaJTa4 - you don't need quotes. You can also use backslashes, or single quotes, depending on the kind of shell you use. But quoting curly brackets appropriately is a matter of your shell and not of Perl. So, maybe tell us what shell you use.

Comment: @Corion I think I will go with the quotes. If the command line is `--multi "key1=abc,key2=123,key3=xwz"` how can I parse the input as I wanted (inserting into `arg` hash).

Comment: If you have a string separated with `=` and `,` and you want to keep the order, you cannot use a hash. If you don't care about the order use `$arg{ multi } = { split /[=,]/, $args{ multi }};`

Comment: @Corion I don't care about the order. Great solution. Is it possible to validate `5`?

Comment: Yes, after assigning to the hash(ref), check that `scalar keys %{ $args{ multi }} < 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following program reads the comma-separated sub-options from the `--multi` option on the command line.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptionsFromArray';

my @args = ('--multi', '{key1=abc,key2=123,key3=xwz}', 'some', 'other');

my %arg;
GetOptionsFromArray(
    \@args,
            "multi=s" => \$arg{"multi"},
);

if( $arg{multi} and $arg{multi} =~ /^\{(.*)\}$/) {
    # split up into hash:
    $arg{ multi } = { split /[{},=]/, $1 };
};

print Dumper \%arg;

__END__

$VAR1 = {
          'multi' => {
                       'key2' => '123',
                       'key1' => 'abc',
                       'key3' => 'xwz'
                     }
        };
```

The program uses `GetOptionsFromArray` for easy testability. In the real program, you will likely use `GetOptions(...)`, which is identical to `GetOptionsFromArray(\@ARGV, ...)`.

Comment: How can I add string before every key, something like `custom.key1,custom.key2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599286/adding-a-string-while-using-the-split-function-perl

Answer (score 2):

One way is to assign options of `key=value` format to a hash, what  [GetOpt::Long allows](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-hash-values). Even better, as this functionality merely needs a hash reference, it turns out that you can have it assign to a hashref that is a value inside a deeper data structure. You can make direct use of that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my %args;
$args{multi} = {}; 

GetOptions( 'multi=s' => $args{multi} ) or die "Bad options: $!";

dd \%args;
```

With multiple invocations of that option the key-value pairs are added

```
script.pl --multi k1=v1 --multi k2=v2
```

and the above program prints

```
{ multi => { k1 => "v1", k2 => "v2" } }
```

I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to print complex data. Change to core `Data::Dumper` if that's a problem.

While `Getopt::Long` has a way to limit the number of arguments that an option takes that apparently applies only for array destinations. So you'd have to count keys to check.

Another way is to [process the input string in a subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options), where you can do practically anything you want. Adding that to the above script, to add yet another key with its hashref to `%args`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my %args;
$args{multi} = {};

GetOptions(
    'multi=s' => $args{multi},
    'other=s' => sub { $args{other} = { split /[=,]/, $_[1] }  }
) or die "Bad options: $!";

dd \%args;
```

When called as

```
script.pl --multi k1=v1 --multi k2=v2  --other mk1=mv1,mk2=mv2
```

This prints

```
{
  other => { mk1 => "mv1", mk2 => "mv2" },
  multi => { k1 => "v1", k2 => "v2" },
}
```