# Adding a string while using the split function [Perl]

Tags: perl, split

I would like to handle a string in Perl. On my previous thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593791/cleanest-way-to-parse-argument-with-getoptlong)) I asked on how to parse options. Consider the following string: `key1=abc,key2=123,key3=xwz`. On the previous thread, I got a suggestion to parse by doing:

```
$arg{"multi"} = { split /[=,]/, $arg{"multi"}};
```

So I get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'multi' => {
                       'key2' => '123',
                       'key1' => 'abc',
                       'key3' => 'xwz'
                     }
        };
```

I would like to insert "custom" before the key, so the output will be:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'multi' => {
                       'custom.key2' => '123',
                       'custom.key1' => 'abc',
                       'custom.key3' => 'xwz'
                     }
        };
```

I can do it by iterating over the keys of the hash, but if it possible, I would like to do it in the same command as `$arg{"multi"} = { split /[=,]/, $arg{"multi"}};`.

I tried putting `custom` before `split` and the `$arg{"multi"}`, but it didn't work as expected. How to solve this issue?

**EDIT:** Is there a way to do so, without importing any new features and modules? If we need to change `$arg{"multi"} = { split /[=,]/, $arg{"multi"}};`, to something else, it is also considered as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use substitution with the `/r` modifier ("return"):

```
$arg{multi} = { split /[,=]/, $string =~ s/(^|,)/$1custom./gr };
```

The `/r` was introduced in Perl 5.14.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pairmap` function from [List::Util](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util):

```
use List::Util 1.29 'pairmap';
$arg{multi} = { pairmap { ("custom.$a" => $b) } split /[=,]/, $arg{multi} };
```

Or since you are creating the hash here, you can simply move the values to the new keys afterward.

```
$arg{multi} = { split /[=,]/, $arg{multi} };
$arg{multi}{"custom.$_"} = delete $arg{multi}{$_} for keys %{$arg{multi}};
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no clean and elegant way to pick out every odd element from a list on the fly, as far as I can tell. One way to do it in one statement

```
use feature 'state';

$arg{multi} = 
    map { state $cnt; (++$cnt % 2 != 0) ? qq(custom.$_) : $_ } 
    split /[=,]/, $arg{multi};
```

Answer (score 2):

Splitting on `=` and splitting on `,` have two different purposes, and now that you going to muck about with one side of the `=` splits, you should consider separating them. This doesn't need to make the operation too inconcise.

```
$arg{"multi"} = { map { ($k,$v)=split/=/; "custom.$k" => $v } split /,/, $str };
```

or

```
$arg{"multi"} = { map { split /=/,"custom.$_"} split /,/,$str };
```